# What are some projects that have taken advantage of Bitcoin's taproot upgrade so far?

Tags: taproot

Are there any projects as of 2022 May that have taken advantage of Bitcoin's taproot upgrade? I'm still trying to understand what can be built with this taproot feature.

Answer (score 1):

Projects that support paying or receiving to P2TR addresses are tracked [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption).

A non-exhaustive list of projects that are working on doing more interesting things taking advantage of Taproot block space savings and improved privacy: Bitcoin Core, rust-bitcoin, btcd, secp256k1-zkp ([MuSig2](https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp/blob/master/examples/musig.c) and [FROST](https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp/pull/138)), lnd/[Taro](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-April/020196.html), Taproot wallets (e.g. [TapWallet](https://github.com/Donno1994/TapWallet)), Taproot scripting tooling (e.g. [btcdeb](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/btcdeb/blob/master/doc/tapscript-example-with-tap.md), [Script Wizard](https://ide.scriptwiz.app/)). There has been a lot of discussion on the lightning-dev [mailing list](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/) and [elsewhere](https://bitcoinops.org/en/preparing-for-taproot/#ln-with-taproot) on how the Lightning Network protocol could upgrade to take advantage of Taproot but at the time of writing that is still at the discussion phase.

Some additional Taproot use cases are listed [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Taproot_Uses).

> I'm still trying to understand what can be built with this taproot feature.

For the most part Taproot doesn't support any **new** functionality (there were no new opcodes added with completely new functionality, just a replacement for OP_CHECKMULTISIG and a tweak to undefined opcodes), what you could do before Taproot you can do after Taproot just with block space savings and improved privacy.

Answer (score 0):

[Citadel](https://github.com/mycitadel/citadel-runtime):

> Bitcoin, LN & RGB wallet runtime supporting Taproot, miniscript,
> descriptors, multisigs, PSBTs